# Delete rows < x to create plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this in a .csv:

```
Consequence,N_samples
A,227
B,413
C,194
D,1
E,1610
F,10
G,7
H,1
I,1
J,5
K,1
L,5
M,5
N,30
O,7
P,3
```

And I want to make a plot pie out of it, but grouping all values lower than 150 into "Other" category. I've tried running this code but it's not working.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotother = {'Consequence' : 'Other', 'N_samples':0}
df=pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep=',')
df = df.append(other,ignore_index=True)
for i in df:
  if (x in df['N_samples']) < 150:
       df['N_samples'].iloc[-1]=df['N_samples'].iloc[-1] + (x in df['N_samples'])
       df.drop([x])
df.plot.pie(label="", title="Consequence", startangle=90);
plot.savefig('Consequence.svg')
```

Once I run it I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "['Consequence'] not found in axis"
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more difficult than it is.

First get all the rows, where sample size is below 150:

```
small_sizes = df[df['N_Samples']<150]
```

The sum up their values:

```
other_samples = small_sizes['N_Samples'].sum()
```

Finally drop the rows and add the `other` row:

```
df = df[~df['N_Samples']<150]
df.loc['other','N_samples'] = other_samples
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Everything worked fine till the last line of code. Got an error in there: 
`ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]`
Even though N_samples format is int64.

Comment: My bad, you need to use loc, not iloc. Iloc expect integer indices.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
```

collect the rows <150 into a new df:

```
df_other=pd.DataFrame([{'Consequence':'Other','N_samples':df[df.N_samples<150].N_samples.sum()}])
```

add that to the rows >= 150 and plot

```
df2=df[df.N_samples>=150]
df3=pd.concat([df2,df_other],axis=0)
df3.plot.pie(y='N_samples',labels=df3['Consequence'])
plt.show()
```

if you find yourself iterating thru a dataframe, be aware there's often a built-in way to do whatever you're trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Define your filtering condition:

```
cond = df.N_samples < 150
```

Sum values from filtering condition:

```
other_sum = df.N_samples[cond].sum()
```

Filter by opposite to condition and add `'other'` row at the bottom in the same line:

```
df = df.loc[~cond].append({'Consequence': 'other', 'N_samples': other_sum}, ignore_index=True)
```